# How to handle required and optional command line arguments?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I want to create a script that has some parameters, like `param1`, `param2`, `param3`. `param1` *must* be set, otherwise it prints an error and exits from the script, whereas the other 2 params are not necessary.

How can I do a main that after having being built if I run `./main param1 abc param2 good` saves in param1 the string `abc` and in param2 the string `good`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package. See the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var param1 string
    var param2 string
    var param3 string
    var param4 string

    flag.StringVar(&param1, "param1", "", "Parameter 1")
    flag.StringVar(&param2, "param2", "", "Parameter 2")
    flag.StringVar(&param3, "param3", "", "Parameter 3")
    flag.StringVar(&param4, "param4", "", "Parameter 4")

    flag.Parse()
    if param1 == "" {
        fmt.Print("Missing required parameter 1 \n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

}
```

Once you have built it, you can run `./main -param1=abc -param2=good` and that will set the `param1` and `param2` variables to `abc` and `good` respectively.

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, I always get that `param1` is missing

Comment: Add a dash before param1 as shown in my edited answer.